# Calculating expectation value of multiplication of two dependent random variables which obey binomial distribution

Tags: expected-value, multinomial-distribution

We have a infinite population of x values obeying some distribution which is known to us. Now we am drawing 10 random samples from that population one at a time and we are creating histogram plot. Now we define two random variables as $f_{i}$ and $f_{j}$ where they represent counts (number of x data points) which falls on i-th and j-th bin respectively when we are creating histogram plot for 10 x values. Now my question is, what will be the value of E($f_{i}f_{j}$)? Probabilities for a x value to belong to i-th and j-th bin are $w_{i}$ and $w_{j}$ respectively.

[image: Here I add my calculation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a much more elegant way to solve your problem without going through all the calculations.

Given a sample size of $n$ you could model the mutual counts in each of the bins of the histogram as a [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) random variable. Let $f_i$ and $f_j$ be the number of observations falling in bin $i$ and $j$ respectively and let $w_i$ and $w_j$ their associated probabilities.

It is then well known from the multinomial distribution that:
\begin{align*}
-nw_iw_j & = cov(f_i,f_j) = \mathbb{E}(f_if_j) -\mathbb{E}(f_i)\mathbb{E}(f_j) = \mathbb{E}(f_if_j) -nw_i n w_j\\
\Rightarrow \qquad & \mathbb{E}(f_if_j)= -nw_iw_j + n^2w_iw_j = nw_iw_j(n-1).
\end{align*}

For your given example this gives $\mathbb{E}(f_if_j) =0.0001235676$, which "coincides" (but is not identical - rounding errors?!) with your calculations/simulation.

(Note however that in your handwritten notes there is likely a mistake: the situation is symmetric for $i$ and $j$ and it doesn't make a lot of sense why one probability should be squared in the end result while the other isn't)

Comment: thank you @chRrr... I also calculated $E(f_i^{2}f_j)$ and $E(f_i^{2}f_j^{2})$ here:: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363731/calculation-of-covariances-covx-i2-x-j-and-covx-i2-x-j2-for-mul

Answer (score 0):

Here, $(f_i+f_j)\leqslant n$.

$E(f_if_j)=\sum_{f_j=0}^{n}f_j \ C_{f_j}^{n} \ w_j^{f_j} \ (1-w_j)^{n-f_j}\sum_{f_i=0}^{n-f_j} \ f_i \ C_{f_i}^{n-f_j} \ w_i^{f_i} (1-w_i)^{n-f_j-f_i} \ (1-w_i)^{f_i}$

Last term $(1-w_i)^{f_i}$ is for nullifying double consideration through the term $(1-w_j)^{n-f_j}$.

I use my data to check the above formula. Since deriving analytic simple form of above formula is hard, I used a program to calculate theoretical value for $n=10$ and then using experimental data I compare results.

Theoretically calculated $E(
f_if_j)$ value is,= $0.00012327$

Experimentally calculated $E(f_if_j)$ value is,= $0.00012933$

$w_i=0.001470181900521$ and $w_j=0.000933879660224$

And in determining experimental value number of times the probability experiment is repeated is, $1082439$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.If you are not sure whether your calculation is wright or wrong ask your new question. If you are sure about your answer state your answer with certainty.